# Detect if a file has been overwritten (Move and Replace) using C#

Tags: c#, windows, file, filesystems

I am currently writing some background processes for a website that are to be run nightly on a webserver.

My main issue is that I need to detect whether an image file has changed in the last 24 hours. I thought that this would be easily achievable using the following code:

```
DateTime lastWrite = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(image.FileName));

if (lastWrite > DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24) && lastWrite < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    var a = "This item has been modified";
}
else
{
    var b = "This item has not been modified";
}
```

however, it seems that this will only give me the DateTime when the file was last modified. This is great for if the image has been edited using something like paint but it does not tell me whether the image has been overwritten using a cut and paste on an existing image as the modified and create date remain the same as the original image that was in place.

My question therefore is how do I detect whether a file (mainly images) have truly been modified (edited, copied over, removed then replaced) within a 24 hour period?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the GetCreationTimeUtc() to deal with the Cut & Paste.

Comment: This won't detect Cut & Paste if the directory that you are pasting the file to already has a file of the same name. If you use the Move and Replace option, the creation time does not change.

Comment: If a method to flag your file is acceptable for you, you can use NTFS Alternate Data Streams (it's like a hidden flag in the file itself, that cannot be in a new file)

Comment: @Xaruth - really interesting, as I read about it though, if the file was copied somewhere, edited a few days ago, and then moved back into that directory the alternate data stream would stay present.

Comment: @RobChurch yes. But you can check at midnight if a file has a "flag" (if not = new file), and if the flag is from the previous night (flagged 24h previously), then update flag with the new date. That's only an example. So more is possible :)

Comment: @Xaruth of course, wasn't thinking about it enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this long-running-page application you'll need to keep a database containing information about the old files. One way of doing this would be to store the MD5 of each file and then compare and copy things that have changed.

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename)) {
    return Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(stream));
}
```

This has the added benefit of allowing you to sync even if some problem means that your "housekeeping" doesn't get run overnight, which will inevitably happen!

Comment: This seems like the best answer so far. I've tested this method thoroughly using different scenarios and it seems foolproof (almost)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other software using the archive file attribute, that will work as you need it to - once you've copied the file to another location, unset the archive attribute. Overwriting the file from another directory will reset it!

```
// Check for flag
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);
bool isArchiveSet = (attributes & File.Archive) == File.Archive

// Remove archive flag
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);
attributes = attributes & ~FileAttributes.Archive;
File.SetAttributes(path, attributes);
```

(Untested code, if you have a problem let me know I'll look at it - but I have tested the behaviour of the archive bit and it does what you want it to).

Comment: This was one of the first things I looked into and unfortunately it didn't work. It would appear that all images are archived by default in the system I tried.

Comment: @jezzipin if you mean that all the files had their bit unset, something else must be using the attribute (because it's that weird way around - Windows automatically sets the bit whenever you change a file, you have to unset it if you've taken your copy). Perhaps you could disable that software or set it to run immediately after your routine?